# Assigning default .value of a spin box

Tags: vb.net

I am having a slight issue with setting the default .value of a spin box to 10. This is controlled by a .TextChanged event. When the .TextChanged occurs, the value of the spin box stays at the value set within the properties, which is 0.

```
'SETS MAX PLAYERS DEPENDING ON txtGameList AND cmbMode
    Private Sub cmbMode_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbMode.TextChanged
        If cmbGamesList.Text = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" And cmbMode.Text = "Competative" Then
            txtMaxPlayers.Maximum = 10
            txtMaxPlayers.Minimum = 1
            txtMaxPlayers.Value = 10
        End If
    End Sub
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to enable me to change this?

Thanks in advance.

Damon

Comment: Hungarian notation is supposed to clarify code.  It does the opposite here, "txt" is for TextBox.  Which doesn't have a Maximum property.  What is a "spin box"??

Comment: My apologies, it is a NumericUpDown, does that make it clearer? It was originally a text box but I am yet to update the code. Hope this clears matters up. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Code works.  Use the debugger to check the values of your, I assume, ComboBoxes.  Using the SelectedIndexChanged event seems more appropriate than the TextChanged event based on the length of your strings.  The proper spelling is "Competitive".

Comment: Thanks LarsTech, pretty embarrassing typo there! Is there any reason why SelectedIndexChanged is better, what is the reasoning behind it depending on string length? Apologies for the second question.

Comment: TextChanged implies the user is typing something.  SelectedIndexChanged is when the user is selecting something in the list.